# Facebook app request shows up in desktop browser but not iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am trying to set up in app facebook game requests for an iOS app.  I am able to successfully send a request from the iOS app and view them in a browser on my laptop.

[image: Game requests show up in a desktop browser]

However, when I try to find the game requests using the facebook app for iOS they don't appear, and neither does my facebook app.

[image: Game requests don't show up in facebook app.]

I want to be able to access these requests so I can make sure that my iOS app will be able to handle opening the link directly.  Here are my app settings as well as plist file.

[image: App settings]
[image: Plist file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to App Details and make sure that under App Center Listed Platforms that iOS - iPad / iOS - Phone were turned on.

[image: iOS turned on under App Center Listed Platforms]